# How to convert multiple column values into rows in hive?

Tags: arrays, hadoop, hive, explode

```
Input:

ID    COLUMN1     COLUMN2             COLUMN3
1     M,S,E,T     1,2,3,4             5,6,7
2     A,B,C       6,5,8,7,9,1         2,4,3,0,1


Output:

ID      COLUMN1      COLUMN2      COLUMN3
1        M           10           50
1        S           20           60
1        E           30           70
1        T           40           NULL
2        A           6            2
2        B           5            4
2        C           8            3 
2        NULL        7            0
2        NULL        9            1
2        NULL        1            NULL
```

Code:

```
select ID,
array_index( COLUMN1_arr, n ) as COLUMN1,
array_index( COLUMN2_arr, n ) as COLUMN2
from sample
lateral view numeric_range(size(COLUMN1_arr)) n1 as n;
```

Error:

> FAILED: Semantic Exception [Error 10011]: Invalid function array_index

Here I'm having a multiple values in single column i need to convert it to rows as mentioned Output.

Answer (score 0):

**Explode** Is an UDTF provided in hive you can use the same to split data from columns into rows.

```
SELECT ID1, col1,col2,col3
FROM tableName 
lateral view explode(split(COLUMN1,',')) cols1 AS col1
lateral view explode(split(COLUMN2,',')) cols2 AS col2
lateral view explode(split(COLUMN3,',')) cols3 AS col3
```

Comment: Have you ever tested such query? multiple lateral views in this case will produce cartesian product

Answer (score 0):

Plain vanilla hive solution, without brickhouse UDFs.

Demo:

```
with 

input as ( ---------------Input dataset
select stack(2,
1, array('M','S','E','T'), array(1,2,3,4),     array(5,6,7),
2, array('A','B','C'),     array(6,5,8,7,9,1), array( 2,4,3,0,1) 
) as (ID,COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3)
),

--explode each array and FULL join them
c1 as (
select i.id, v.column1, p
  from input i
       lateral view posexplode(i.COLUMN1) v as p,column1
),

c2 as (
select i.id, v.column2, p
  from input i
       lateral view posexplode(i.COLUMN2) v as p,column2
),

c3 as (
select i.id, v.column3, p
  from input i
       lateral view posexplode(i.COLUMN3) v as p,column3
)

--FULL JOIN
select coalesce(c1.id,c2.id,c3.id) id, c1.column1, c2.column2, c3.column3
  from c1 
       full join c2 on c1.id=c2.id and c1.p=c2.p
       full join c3 on nvl(c1.id,c2.id)=c3.id and nvl(c1.p,c2.p)=c3.p --note NVL usage
;
```

Result:

```
OK
id      column1 column2 column3
1       M       1       5
1       S       2       6
1       E       3       7
1       T       4       NULL
2       A       6       2
2       B       5       4
2       C       8       3
2       NULL    7       0
2       NULL    9       1
2       NULL    1       NULL
```